# Use JavaScript string as function name?

Tags: javascript

I need to call a function in the following fashion:

```
var f = 'fadeOut';
$(v).f(s, function(){
    $(v).css('visibility', 'hidden').css('position', 'absolute');
});
```

Is this possible to do simply?

Comment: Please have a look at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619046/javascript-variable-function-name. It's not the same question exactly, but I feel it may prove useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call a JavaScript function name using a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496961/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-name-using-a-string) , Call a function in JavaScript by its name? , etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes

```
var f = 'fadeOut';
$(v)[f](s, function(){
    $(v).css('visibility', 'hidden').css('position', 'absolute');
});
```

Comment: Any property of an object can be accessed with dot-syntax or square brackets. The latter though the only way to use if the property contains spaces or other disallowed characters

Comment: @BorisShemigon You are correct, however you cannot access a property with dot syntax via a string variable, in that case you must use brackets or utilize `eval` which I do not recommend.