# Calling Javascript Functions by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

If I have an element on the page like this ...

```
<span data-function="DoSomething">Click</span>
```

... and i put this in my page header ...

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
   $('[data-function]').each(function()
   {
       var fName = $(this).attr('data-function');
       $(this).click(fName);
   });
});
```

... what goes in place of the comment produce the desired effect of executing the function called "DoSomething".

Note:
I no the code above wont work, my question is how to make this work (translate 'DoSomething' in to DoSomething();)

Any ideas guys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619046/use-javascript-variable-as-function-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions should be available. Try putting them in an Object, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
   var fns = {
      DoSomething: function() {/* ... */},
      DoAnotherthing: function() {/* ... */}
   };
   $('[data-function]').each(function()
   {
       var fName = $(this).attr('data-function');
       $(this).click(fns[fName]);
   });
});
```

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/HfNke/), demonstrating a way to keep everything local to one namespace and assigning handlers based on the `data` attribute of elements.

Comment: I love this, it pushes the JS in to a more object oriented model instead of the typical "quick and dirty solution" i'm finding myself implementing a lot (dispirate functions with no relationships unlike something like C# on the server which forces you to group your functions in to classes giving your code structure)

Comment: @Wardy, yep, that's the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling function with window object -

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
        $('[data-function]').each(function() {
            var fName = $(this).attr('data-function');

            if (typeof (window[fName]) === "function") {
                $(this).click(window[fName]); 
            }
        });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
$(this).click(window[fName]);
```

Where `window` would be replaced by the appropriate expression if the function `DoSomething` is not defined in the global scope.

Comment: probably a stupid question but ... what is the "appropriate expression" / how is it determined?

Comment: @Wardy: "It depends" (on your code). If you define it as a global function it's `window`. Or it could be something like Kooilnc's example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit clean way:

http://jsfiddle.net/whsPG/

```
var myfuncs = {
  alert : function() {
        alert("An Alert");
    },
    changeName: function(obj) {
        $(obj).text('Other Text');
    }    
};

$('[data-function]').on('click', function()
{
  value =  $(this).data('function');

   if (myfuncs.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
     myfuncs[value](this);
   }
```

});
​