# Javascript Element.onclick = functionName(as String)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have function name in a var,

```
var i = 2; // iteration
var fname = 'myFunction' + i; // looks like myFunction2()
```

now i want to assign this function on element's event. i.e.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('e');
elem.onclick = fname;
```

It doesn't work. JS take function name as 'fname()' not the string inside it 'myFunction2()'

A little help would be appriciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can be done with [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) But remember, eval = evil..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
window['myFunction' + i]
```

or create a array/object of functions.

```
var i = 2; // iteration
var fname = 'myFunction' + i; // looks like myFunction2()
var elem = document.getElementById('e');
elem.onclick = window[fname];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will execute the function right away, am i right? i want the function to be assigned to element 'e'. when mouse clicked on element 'e' then function invoked.

Comment: no... this wont execute the function...

Comment: Oh wow, your added section "or create a array/object of functions." works like a charm bro!! Thanxxxx alot :D

Answer (score -1):

Check these answers: [Javascript - Variable in function name, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733580/javascript-variable-in-function-name-possible)
and [Use JavaScript variable as function name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619046/use-javascript-variable-as-function-name)

What you attempt is to assign a string (variable) on an event.