# Javascript use variable name to thread a function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

In GSC, you are able to make a variable become the name of a function that you thread. It looks like this:

```
variable = "pizza";
[[variable]]();
```

the engine then reads it like:

```
pizza();
```

my question is, is it possible to do that in javascript as easily or do I have to make if/else/switch statements for it?

Comment: There are many similar questions, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619046/use-javascript-variable-as-function-name?rq=1

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript

Comment: By "thread", you mean "call"?

Comment: @b2238488: Not really, that one talks about creating functions

Comment: that is for jquery... also GSC is a scripting language for COD.

Comment: What is "COD" ? Can include meanings of letters in acronyms "GSC" "COD" , at Question ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @guest271314: he seems to refer to http://cod1.eu/script/dm.gsc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is, is it possible to do that in javascript as easily or
>   do I have to make if/else/switch statements for it?

If you want to use the safe, fail-proof way, then you can access such variables only in two contexts.

1. If the variable is in global context, in the case of which, you can do `window[variable]();`
2. Else if the variable is a property of an object, in the case of which, you can do `obj_name[variable]()`, basically anything that can be accessed via bracket notation. `window` is an object too.

---

Then there's always the dirty way:

- You can use highly evil `eval` like `eval(variable + "()")` or you can use the `Function` constructor in the same way. Note however that both the methods can be misused and are highly advised against.